# What is the best way to generate an URL that expires in 3 days?

Tags: php, html

Hello to all of you developers,

I wanted to make a web page in php that can only be accessed through a generated URL , that webpage can only be accessible 3 days with that generated URL. After that , the user can no longer access that page.

What is your best advice to do that?

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT** : Thank you very much for all of your answers and consideration into this subject , surely it helped me a lot.

Comment: you make your CMS (even if you wrote it yourself) store a list of temporary URLs and their creation/duration, then delete expired URLs from that list. Bonus points for _not_ doing that as part of a URL request because it's not PHP's job to do db maintenance. Use a not-meant-to-die-after-30-seconds language for that, and cron it so it runs once a day (or once an hour or something). However, since you don't say anything about what you're actually using: that's guesswork, so update your post to include actual details please.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? I don't think there is one "best way" to do this

Comment: How about trying [temporary expiring link generator](https://expiry.link), its the quick way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method is to use a JWT-like method. You put a private key on your server. Your server generate url like `http://my-url?expireAt=20210401&sign=XXXXXX`, where the `sign` is the signature. Then, when the user visits this page, the server not only check whether current time is before expireAt time, and also *check the signature* to see whether the paramters is generated by the server (or by a bad user himself).

P.S. You may need some basic knowledge in cryptography to understand the answer. It is a very commonly used idea :)

**EDIT:**

Here is an example - **how AWS shares a file with a presigned url**. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

> When you create a presigned URL for your object, you must provide ... expiration date and time. The presigned URLs are valid only for the specified duration.

That's exactly what you want :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the signature? What if a user keeps the signature same and tweaks the value in expireAt?

Comment: @nice_dev please learn some cryptography ;) Indeed, if expireAt (or your `my-url`) changes, the signature should be different

Comment: Ok, I overlooked that the signature is derived from expireAt and secret key. I initially _assumed_ that they are being operated differently.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @ch271828n , it helped me a lot !

Comment: @ItZSk1llz You are welcome! :) If the answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by use of "Shot code" concept, where all the details will be saved against 6 or 7 random alphanumeric string based on your frequency of url generations. You can also change expiry of the urls based on your requirements.

URL FORMAT:
[http://example.com/your_page_name?q=**{shot_code}*](http://example.com/your_page_name?q=**%7Bshot_code%7D*)*

Example:
**http://example.com/your_page_name?q=5rutvfry**

```
Your Record in your DB:
id      shot_code     expiry_time               details...
1       5rutvfry      2021-05-16 10:41:08       abcd
2       t6rtf7if      2021-05-16 10:41:08       pqr
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much @baijugoradia , seems pretty interesting this "Shot Code" concept , never heard about it. I'll explore it further about this subject.

Comment: Can you share more details about this concept? Working with PHP since more than ten years, I've never heard the term "Shot code"

Comment: @NicoHaase so the shot code is would be a reference column where all codes will be unique to that column. this shot code can be generated by shuffling alphanumeric string.

Comment: Please add all clarification, including some reference to the inventors of such concept, to your answer by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase, its not a invention just a concept for approaching the situation where you want to either generate temporary url's where you have full control over the url and the data OR you can use it for creating shorter url's representing long urls (this is how url shortener work).

Comment: And who coined the term "shot code"? What does "shot" stand for?

Comment: @NicoHaase "shot code" is just the term used for easy understanding nothing else. Just consider it as unique id for each record. Shot means small and code is set of random alphanumeric characters in this context.